# View default record type on all the objects on a particular profile

Tags: profile, record-type, configuration, object, admin

Is there any way we can view the default record type for all the objects custom/standar for a particular profile rather than going on each object and checking its default record type  because there are more than 700 objects in our org and it will take forever to do this .
Any leads,workaround will be helpful
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can go to 
Setup -> Profile -> System Administrator (can be any profile; Click on this name)

Look under the **Record Type Settings** section, it will show all the available record type for the object and the default selection for the profile you are viewing.

Edit:
[image]
I just created 2 record types for Account to demonstrate what I meant. This is for System Administrator profile. If I have more record types for the other objects, it will show there and the default record type will have **(default)** labelled beside the record type name.

Comment: Hi Prem I am aware of this but is there any way we can see the default record type of all the objects for a particular profile rather than opening one object at a time because there are more than 700 objects .

Comment: You don’t have to open each object to see the default recordType. If you do the steps above, it will show you the default recordType of the object for the profile your are viewing. For example, let’s say you have 2 recordTypes in Account object called Rt_A and Rt_B and assume Rt_B is the default recordType for System Administrator profile. Now if you, view the profile under Record Type Settings, under Account you can see something like; Account: Rt_A, Rt_B (default). I have edited my answer above to show what I mean in an image form :)

Comment: Wohoo thanks a ton you saved me from spending lot of hours :)